# Updating two tables at once with values off the first one, and a variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to update with a passed variable in only the first row that has value NULL (multiple rows could have NULL in this column, but I need just the one),
Then I need to get the row affected (the primary key) and update the other table with it.

Here's what my two tables look like:

```
table1
id | some_value | ref_table2_id_fk

table2
id |    name    | ref_table1_id_fk
```

In my stored procedure I'm grabbing the passed value as `@passed as int`, then I try the following:

```sql
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @id AS INT;
    DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int);
     BEGIN TRANSACTION;
     BEGIN TRY

        UPDATE TOP (1) [dbo].table1
            SET ref_table2_id_fk = @passed
            OUTPUT inserted.id INTO @temp
            WHERE ref_table2_id_fk = NULL

        UPDATE [dbo].table2
            SET ref_table1_id_fk = @temp.id
            FROM table2
            JOIN @temp i on i.id = table2.id;

        SET @id = @@IDENTITY

     END TRY
     BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
         --some error
         ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;
         RETURN 0;
        END
     END CATCH;

      IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
        BEGIN
         --success
         COMMIT TRANSACTION;     
         RETURN @Id;
        END

END
```

As pointed out by Dale @@identity doesn't work in update. My intention is to simply know if the transaction went through or not.

Comment: Do you commit your transaction?

Comment: Also, your top(1), how do you know which NULL row you'll update?

Comment: it should always be the one first row with NULL in that column

Comment: `@passed` goes into first row with NULL in column 3 in table1. Table2 will take the row affected id and reference it in table2.column3 where `table2.id = @passed`

Answer (score 1):

I think the following code does what you are asking. Things fixed:

1. `where ref_table2_id_fk = null` should be `where ref_table2_id_fk is null`
2. You can't use `TOP` in an `update` statement you need a sub-query to get the id.
3. You're not providing an `id` in `@temp` to join onto `table2` - you need the `table1` id and the `table2` id for a joined update.
4. If I understand your logic the id you want to return is `@passed` - you already have it.
5. `@temp.id` should be `i.id` since you've (rightly) aliased it

```
    declare @Passed int = 3;

    declare @table1 table (id int, some_value varchar(12), ref_table2_id_fk int);
    declare @table2 table (id int, some_value varchar(12), ref_table1_id_fk int);

    insert into @table1 (id)
      select 1 union all select 2;

    insert into @table2 (id)
      select 3 union all select 4;

    select * from @table1;
    select * from @table2;

    DECLARE @id AS INT, @Result bit = 0;
    DECLARE @temp TABLE (id int, fk int);

    BEGIN TRANSACTION;
    BEGIN TRY

      UPDATE @table1
        SET ref_table2_id_fk = @passed
      OUTPUT @passed, inserted.id INTO @temp
      WHERE id = (
        select top 1 id
        from @table1
        where ref_table2_id_fk is NULL
        -- Optionally order by if you have a priority here
      );

      UPDATE T2
        SET ref_table1_id_fk = i.fk
      FROM @table2 T2
      JOIN @temp i on i.id = T2.id
      where T2.id = @passed;

      -- If we get here then everything worked
      -- Return @Result at the end of the proc
      SET @Result = 1;

    END TRY
    begin catch
      no_op:;
    end catch

    select * from @table1;
    select * from @table2;
```

Comment: `@passed` is not what I want returned, I simply want to know if the transaction went through or not.